# Is there a way to use a conditional when declaring method variables?

Tags: c#, methods, variable-declaration

Maybe I am missing the correct language to describe this, but I am trying to utilize a pre-existing method with a different BO than currently passed.

I guess it would be something like:

```
public override SetInsurance(BusinessObjects.Utilities.LandViewer Viewer_land || BusinessObjects.Utilities.SeaViewer Viewer_sea, DataTable patient, int InsurancePriority)
{
}
```

Any help is appreciated as this might just not exist.

*//Note that these BOs are 95 percent similar but combining them is not an option in our codebase.

Comment: you should read up on generics. or inheritance and give them both a common baseclass. or interfaces.

Comment: Would it be possible to define an interface that both of the business objects would then implement? Can you modify the business objects in at least that degree?

Comment: `Function overloading` can help.

Answer (score 2):

You should take the bits that are 95% similar (or at least the bits you'd like to use in this and other methods that can work with either type), and put them in an interface, say `interface IViewer`.  Have both `LandViewer` and `SeaViewer` implement that interface, and have the method take it, eg:

```
interface IViewer {
    string Name {get;set;}
}

class LandViewer: IViewer {
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int SomeValue;
}
class SeaViewer: IViewer {
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string SomeOtherValue;
}

public override SetInsurance(IViewer viewer, DataTable patient, int InsurancePriority) {
    Console.WriteLine(viewer.Name); //.Name is accessible as it's part of the 95%

    // .SomeValue and .SomeOtherValue are not accessible, because they're not part of the 95% 
}
```